# MonoDevelop does not underline errors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, underline

I am using MonoDevelop 4 for Unity, but it does not underline errors. The "Underline errors" option under "Markers and Rulers" is checked, the "Build project in MonoDevelop" is also checked, but none of the errors are underlined. I sometimes make syntax errors and I have to go back to Unity to find them. It is making me crazy, how can I fix it? Nothing shows up from a Google search.

Comment: what exact version of MonoDevelop are you using? "4" is a bit generic

Comment: It is 4.0.1 which comes bundled with Unity

Comment: that version is very old, apparently now you can use the latest versions of MonoDevelop (in Mac and Windows it's called Xamarin Studio) along with a new Unity add-in

Comment: The MonoDevelop that Unity uses is developed by Unity Team and 4.0.1 is the latest one for Unity. Can you elaborate your answer? How do I use MonoDevelop 4.2.2 with Unity?

Comment: there's a unity add-in for MonoDevelop 4.2.x, install it and look for it in the add-in manager